# Can you use firebase "callable functions" in angularfire2?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

Is it possible to use "Callable Functions" together with AngularFire2?

Since AngularFireModule already calls initializeApp, I am not sure how to follow the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#initialize_the_client_sdk)?

I guess I should not call initializeApp() multiple times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularFire2 is built on top of the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK. That means that anything that's possible in the JavaScript SDK, is also possible from within AngularFire2. If the action is related to showing data from Firebase in UI elements, there may be a wrapper from AngularFire. But even if there is no wrapper, you can access the JavaScript SDK directly.

So: Yes, it is possible to invoke Callable Cloud Functions from AngularFire2. You should indeed only initialize the app once, unless you're trying to access multiple projects.

If you're having trouble making this work, post the [minimal, complete code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. I just read in the documentation that it is currently not possible to test Callable Cloud Functions - so I will stop for now trying to integrate. But thanks for the clarification. I always try to provide the minimal, complete code but it also takes a huge effort to get up and running.